# Inequality:$e^{-x} \sin x < \frac{x}{1+x}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Show that $e^{-x} \sin x < \frac{x}{1+x},x>0$.

Trial: Let $f(x)=e^{-x} \sin x - \frac{x}{1+x}$ So, $f'(x)=e^{-x}(\cos x- \sin x)-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$. From here I can't conclude anything. I also think about series of $e^{-x},\sin x , (1+x)^{-1}$.But I am unable to solve.Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Using this inequality: If $x>0$, then
$$e^x > 1+x$$
and
$$\sin x < x$$

Comment: +1 Nice. Just a little thing: multiplying the inequalities works fine as long as $\sin x >0\,$ , otherwise...well, otherwise the wanted inequality is trivial, yet some little care is required here.